# I need multicolumn lookup combobox component

Tags: delphi, c++builder, lookup

In Delphi/C++ Builder classic TDBLookupCombobox only shows one column. I order to show multiple columns (dataset fields) in lookup combobox I need another component. I tried using TAdvDBLookupComboBox from TMS, but it is so bugged it's useless to waste time on it. Anyone else know such component? It does not have to be free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of DevExpress VCL Component, like TcxLookupComboBox or TcxPopupEdit or TcxExtLookupComboBox.